# Hibernate Query not recognizing FETCH

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, hql

I have two tables, `first_table` and `second_table`, which I'm joining. second_table contains a @OneToMany relationship with records table. This relationship is marked with FetchType.Lazy. When I run the query below, I get this exception indicating that the FETCH is not recognized

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
... 
SELECT * 
  FROM first_table f 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN second_table s ON f.id = s.id 
  JOIN FETCH[*] second_table.records
...
```

JPARepository native query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM first_table f 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN second_table s ON f.id = s.id 
  JOIN FETCH second_table.records
```

Comment: Should it just be SELECT * 
  FROM first_table f 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH second_table s ON f.id = s.id

Comment: @RobertBain No this results in the same problem, also this does not specify the relationship I mentioned to be fetched.                                                
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT * FROM first_table f LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH[*]